# Changed Django model attribute and now getting error for it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had a model with a DateField that worked just fine. I wanted to change it from a DateField to a CharField.

**Before:**

```
class NWEAScore(models.Model):

    test_date = models.DateField(default=date.today, verbose_name='Test Date')
```

**After:**

```
class NWEAScore(models.Model):

    year = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=SIXTEEN)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SESSION_CHOICES, default=FALL)
```

Not sure what went wrong but now I'm getting an error.

Making migrations is no problem. I make them and then upload them to my server, then when I migrate, I get an error.
The Error I get when I try to apply my migrations:

```
(venv) alex@newton:~/newton$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, amc, auth, brain, contenttypes, ixl, nwea, sessions
Running migrations:
Rendering model states... DONE
Applying brain.0021_auto_20160927_0038... OK
Applying nwea.0011_auto_20160927_0038...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 612, in get_field
return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'test_date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 202, in handle
targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 132, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 237, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 525, in database_forwards
getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 329, in alter_unique_together
self._delete_composed_index(model, fields, {'unique': True}, self.sql_delete_unique)
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 352, in _delete_composed_index
columns = [model._meta.get_field(field).column for field in fields]
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 352, in <listcomp>
columns = [model._meta.get_field(field).column for field in fields]
File "/home/alex/newton/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 614, in get_field
raise FieldDoesNotExist('%s has no field named %r' % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: NWEAScore has no field named 'test_date'
```

I went through and deleted all my instances from all my models, just incase a remaining "NWEAScore" Instance with a test_date was throwing the error.

I searched through my entire project for the term "test_date", trying to delete every instance, and the only remaining instances are in old migrations. Should I go back and delete those? Could that be throwing that off? I'm not too clear on how to wipe migrations and make new ones if that's it.

I gave it a shot for a few days, if anyone has suggestions thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the *migrations* folder of your app and delete all files, except `__init__.py`. Then run the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

to make new migrations with the updated fields

Comment: @AlexTrost Yes, that too

Comment: Deleted it all and ran migrations. It created a new 0001_initial.py and gave me this:


`(newton) TrostMacbook:newton alexandertrost$ python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'nwea':
  nwea/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model NWEAScore
    - Create model NWEASkill
    - Create model RITBand
    - Add field rit_band to nweaskill
    - Alter unique_together for nweascore (1 constraint(s))`

Comment: But when I Migrate it says no migrations to apply:  

`(venv) alex@newton:~/newton$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, amc, auth, brain, contenttypes, ixl, nwea, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply`

Comment: @AlexTrost Delete your previous database

Comment: Sorry to keep going back and asking for more help in the comments like this, but what's the best way to do that without throwing django and PSQL out of sync? Last time I went into PSQL and started deleting stuff I did just that.

I don't use South, but after this I think I'll start.

Comment: @AlexTrost If you're starting off with your DB design, you may use SQLite which is easy to delete. If you insist on doing scratch work with legacy DB, then south migrations is one way to go.